# rsyslog errors flooding log

Tags: permissions, apache2, rsyslog

Ubuntu 18.04LTS server, My log is suddenly flooded with rsyslog errors:

```
Jan  5 19:17:01 servername rsyslogd: action 'action 13' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  5 19:17:01 servername rsyslogd: action 'action 13' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

There are thousands of these action 13 entries in the log.  I think the root of the problem is these two permissions issues:

```
Jan  6 06:27:05 servername rsyslogd: file '/var/log/apache2/access.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan  6 06:27:05 servername rsyslogd: file '/var/log/apache2/cgi.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
```

I have done nothing to change anything related to rsyslog that I know of These errors began after applying some Ubuntu updates/patches.

What should /var/log/apache2 and sub-folder/files permissions and ownership look like?

Why is rsyslog flooding my logs with thousands of these errors, its obscuring other potentially important stuff!

Comment: All files in `/var/log/apache2` ought to be 640 (that is `rw-r-----`) and owned by `root:adm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make `syslog` owner of this file 
Example for `cron.log`:

```
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               708 Mar 28 01:02 cron.log
```

At least this fixed the error for me...

Comment: "Try to make syslog owner of this file" indeed fixes the problem.  Applied to both /var/log/apache2/access.log and error.log files.