# syslog errors and apache2

Tags: apache2, rsyslog

This is a follow-on to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201035/rsyslog-errors-flooding-log)...

So I can change the ownership of the log file, and the errors stop.  I changed the ownership from root:adm to syslog:adm and the errors cease.  But when the logs get rotated, the NEW log is created with root:adm ownership, and the flood of errors reappears.  I would like to a) understand how this works and b) fix the errors so they do not reoccur.

Is there a config file somewhere which sets the ownership of the apache log files so this can be fixed permanently?

Edited To Add:

meuh is correct.  Found /etc/logrotate.d/apache2:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
daily
missingok
rotate 14
compress
delaycompress
notifempty
create 640 root adm
sharedscripts
postrotate
            if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
                invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
            fi;
endscript
prerotate
    if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
    fi; \
endscript
}
```

Changed "create 640 root adm" to "create 640 syslog adm" and errors ended after next cron "daily" run.

Comment: Often, logs are rotated by the `logrotate` utility. Look for config files in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*` and the `create` keyword.

Comment: @meuh correct, see ETA on original post

Comment: Good solution. You can put your discovery and fix as an answer, then you can accept your own answer, hence keeping question and fix separate.